# Canvas element + Javascript working in Chrome and Firefox, not in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, html5-canvas, leaflet

I am using a modified version of the Leaflet [FullCanvas Plugin](https://github.com/cyrilcherian/Leaflet-Fullcanvas) to draw lines on a map. These lines work perfectly find on Firefox and Chrome, but on Internet Explorer (version 11, I'm using Windows 8.1) these lines never get reset when moving/zooming the map. I made a Fiddle to illustrate the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/tee99z65/

Try dragging and zooming while on Chrome or Firefox, and then Internet Explorer (11). What is going on in this code? The method that gets called every time the lines need to be redrawn is **drawCanvas()** :

```
drawCanvas: function () {
        var canvas = this.getCanvas();
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var me = this;
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        var bounds = this._myMap.getBounds();
        if (!this.options.filterPointsInBounds) bounds = new L.LatLngBounds([-90, -180], [90, 180]);
        var points = this._myQuad.retrieveInBounds(this.boundsToQuery(bounds));
        points.forEach(function (point) {
            var d = point.data;
            if (d.draw && !d.draw(d)) return;    // allows dynamic filtering of curves
            var spoint = me._myMap.latLngToContainerPoint(new L.LatLng(d.slat, d.slon));
            if (d.tlat && d.tlon) {
                var tpoint = me._myMap.latLngToContainerPoint(new L.LatLng(d.tlat, d.tlon));
                me.drawCurve(point, spoint, tpoint, d.style ? d.style(d) : null);
            }
        });
    },
```

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here? A fix would be nice, but I'm already happy if anyone can point out **why** this is happening so I can attempt a fix myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved:

http://jsfiddle.net/tee99z65/3/

The function that draws the curve, drawCurve(), has been edited from:

```
ctx.moveTo(startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(px, py, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);
ctx.stroke();
```

To:

```
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo(startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
 ctx.quadraticCurveTo(px, py, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.closePath();
```

Lesson learned: never forget about beginPath() and closePath().

Answer (score 1):

**Why?**

Because mousewheel events are not yet standardized. (Note to browser makers: *Seriously!???*, why have you not standardized the mousewheel event yet. Scrolling mice have been around for years! -- end of rant/ ).

**Fix:**

You will have to listen for the `mousewheel` event on IE instead of the `DOMMouseScroll` event that most other browsers listen for. I don't work with leavlet, but that appears to be where you need to add the fix.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I'm already on my way home, but will try to replace the offending event listeners with jQuery ones tomorrow.

Comment: I tried something else first, I added a simple console.log to the drawCanvas function: http://jsfiddle.net/tee99z65/2/
Both dragging around the map and zooming the map logs a message to the console. This works on IE11 as well, so the mouse events are recognized and the function gets called. Or am I misunderstanding your explanation the cause of the problem?

Comment: A bug that took the better part of yesterday got solved in less than an hour today... Frig my life. See my solution. Thanks for trying to help anyway markE!